# Identifying users that click on an ad via API

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, ads

Is there any way to access the Facebook UID for a user that clicks on a marketplace ad that is created using the Ad API without app authentication via Open Graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. They have to authenticate your app before you have a chance to see their UID. If you could get their UIDs, you could spam them and Facebook doesn't want this.

Comment: What about accessing anonymous graph data RE: connections / interests

Comment: You'll have to see if what you want is available through the insights [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/) / [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/) tables. Take a look at your ad's insights tab first. This will give you a better idea where to start.